# Should I put let values out of for loops to get better performance?

Tags: swift, performance, for-loop, let

For example, if I have code like this

```
for i in 1 ... 10000 {
    let someValue = 9
    ...
}
```

Should I put the let value out of the loop, so I can get better performance or is it totally unnecessary?

```
autoreleasepool {
    let someValue = 9
    for i in 1 ... 10000 {
        ...
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: counter question: Why would you have it in the loop's body?

Comment: @vikingosegundo As it is only needed there. That also why I use autoreleasepool in the other codes as I don't want it in the other scopes.

Comment: autoreleasepool is a rather bad idea for scoping. use methods and implicites for creating smaller scopes.

Comment: It is not only related to the time it takes. It is wronged, it is unnecessary to allocate memory each time if you're using always the same value. You are allocating and deallocating memory in each cycle, it takes time and memory if you'll use bigger object than an Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For types which can be initialized very quickly you probably don't need to use the second version since this would only result in a minor performance improvement.

The compiler could also optimize it away. Especially in case of `structs` and `enums` because they cannot be mutated at all. Although with classes you can mutate its contents and if the compiler cannot check at compile time whether it is mutated it cannot be optimized.

All in all for such a simple case with `Int` it's up to you which one do you use since there is almost no performance improvement assuming you do some heavy stuff (more than just initializing an `Int`) inside the for loop.

Note: For different scoping Swift 2 introduced `do {}`:

```
do {
    let someValue = 9
    for i in 1 ... 10000 {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have create a new command line project and use @CodyWeaver 's method. In a test of 1 million loops, the performance lost is only 1/1000. So I believe either way is OK. Thanks.

Comment: I already give you a upvote, which makes it from -1 to 0. I don't know why there is a downvote as I think your answer should not be downvoted.

Comment: @CodyWeaver OwenZhao Please move to chat if it doesn't relate to this question.

Comment: @Qbyte where can I find chat?

Answer (score 1):

**Outside**

```
let a = NSDate()
for i in 1...100 {
    let someValue = a
    print("Hello World!")
}
let b = NSDate()
let c: Double = b.timeIntervalSinceDate(a)
print(c)

let d = NSDate()
let someValue = a
for i in 1...100 {
    print("Hello World!")
}
let e = NSDate()
let f: Double = e.timeIntervalSinceDate(d)
print(f)
```

In a playground on a MacBook Air running the latest version of OSX 
c = 0.092 and f = 0.022

Seems like you need to reword the question. If the constant won't mutate then it should be outside of the loop.  A loop is for a repetitive code that need to mutate. Outside is always better because inside you have to allocate another instance i times instead of doing it once.

Comment: Your method seams good for me. However, I wonder if the answer is the same if the code is compiled in a .swift file? As playground is runs as line by line.

Comment: Unfortunately a playground is not the best place to test this but if you add the code as a source file (to the playground) or even make a new project where you can adjust the optimization you can get more reliable results.